# getting variable from another php-file from line

Tags: php

getting variable from another php-file from line

Hello
Is it possible to get a value from another PHP file
Reading variable from specific line
Example

file1.php

```
<?php
echo 'my variable is';
//reading the variable from line 3
?>
```

file2.php

```
<?php
/*this  is line 1*/
/*this  is line 2*/
$var = 'hello world'; /*this  is line 3*/
?>
```

Comment: This might help you >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135131/php-getting-variable-from-another-php-file?rq=1

Comment: Is it possible to read from  specific line the variable

Answer (score 1):

Use include or require in file1.php :

```
<?php
include 'file2.php';
//require 'file2.php';
echo 'my variable is '.$var;
//reading the variable from line 3
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can [include](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) the file in the page.