# Accessing PHP variables from PHP files with HTML

Tags: php, html

The thing is, i have a link in a PHP file 1`links.php` that has `html` in it. The link is like

`<a href="page.php?link=$link">Links</a>`

The thing is that if i am accessin the `$link variable` from `page.php` i would have done

`$links = (int)$_GET['link'];`

But i am not accessing the `$link` from `page.php` but an entirely different say `page2.php`

I can't use `include ("page.php")` because it would include also the `html` and `css` and i don't want that. I just want the `$link variable`.

Any advice is acceptable. Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove JavaScript and jQuery tag

Comment: check this link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135131/php-getting-variable-from-another-php-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [session variable](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_sessions.htm) in this case

**File1:-**

```
<?php
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['link'] = "your_value";
?>
```

**File2:-**

```
<?php
     session_start();
     echo empty($_SESSION['link']) ? 'not set' : $_SESSION['link'];
?>
```

Answer Source:- [PHP, getting variable from another php-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135131/php-getting-variable-from-another-php-file)

Comment: I can't do this because if i already have a login session, it picks the `hash` from the user logged in `id`.

Comment: You can add any numbers of session variables. Why don't you add another variable?

Comment: Oh. Finally got it working. Thanks for getting me out of this. Really need to work on my `PHP` skills and knowledge. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

store the $link variable content in the session variable and use it across the application.