# how to access an element that included using php file

Tags: php

I set template php scripts in order to easily make a change to the file. I have index.php as main page and two php scripts footer.php and header.php. I included two of them in index.php. My question is can access html elements inside footer.php from header.php?

> index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div class="header"><?php require "templates/header.php" ?></div>
    <div class="footer"><?php require "templates/footer.php" ?></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

> header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
 <head>
  <script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#footerDiv").css('display','none');
    });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

> footer.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
 <head>
  <script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#footerDiv").css('display','block');
    });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="footerDiv">
   <p>I wanted to access this div from header.php</p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: include your file then you can access

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135131/php-getting-variable-from-another-php-file

Comment: probably you want a better start in web software engeneering for that. Like some small MVC code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first create index.php file like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header"><?php require "header.php" ?></div>
  <div class="footer"><?php require "footer.php" ?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

then create header.php file like this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#footerDiv").css('display','none');
  });

</script>
```

then create footer.php file like this

```
<div id="footerDiv">
  <p>I wanted to access this div from header.php</p>
 </div>
```

finally run index.php then you can see footer content hide

Comment: I added a code, please can you see it and say something #Shafiqul

Comment: you want to access mean you want to get text from header ?

Comment: yest everything, as I did in header.php, i want to change styles of the div, i've tried but not working for me, when I run index.php.

Comment: im sorry, but im not getting the change you made, everything is the same with the one I posted... can you describe it for me...

Comment: i have tested and working fine in my end and i am sure it will work

Comment: i didn't actually, and I'll, can you tell me the reason why the code I wrote is not working. I want to know the reason too...

Comment: your code format is not good . you include file and also add body , html tag etc , i remove this and update this code and working fine

Comment: why you use this code two time?
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#footerDiv").css('display','block');
    });
  </script>

Comment: you include this footer and header in index.php file so first you hide this footer and again you show this so last show will happen . and no need to include same file in both header and footer

Comment: actually added it for demonstration, ow then should I remove all html, body, head... but I want to organize because incase I use many div's or other html elements....

Comment: yes not need html , body , doc type in header and footer file cause it is already added in index file and you just include all content using include method .

Comment: i mean this is content no need remove 
<div id="footerDiv">
   <p>I wanted to access this div from header.php</p>
  </div>, but same this remove which already have in index.php file like <!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
 <head>

Comment: just review my answer structure then you will get idea