# Transfer Variable

Tags: php, get, http-post, environment-variables

How can I get a Variable from another PHP Script?

```
$test = $_POST['a'];
```

but I want this:

```
$test= $_POST[$a];
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you give a more complete example of what your trying to achieve.  Preferably an example that others can use to recreate this.

Comment: I have two PHP Scripts and want to use the variable from the first Script in the second Script as well

Comment: You can use session for that.

Comment: include the first script in the second?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP, getting variable from another php-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135131/php-getting-variable-from-another-php-file)