# how do I make a php variable successfully available in another php file?

Tags: php

I have 2 php files inside joomla and I want to make a variable from php-file 1 available in php-file 2.

php-file_1.php

```
$a_variable = $input->getString('text');
```

php-file_2.php

```
include(php-file_1.php);
echo $a_variable;
```

I get Notice: Undefined variable: a_variable in /var/www/vhosts/a_domain.de/httpdocs/php-file_2.php on line 2

what's wrong here?

Comment: Try include "php-file_1.php";

Comment: I just searched stackoverflow for "php access variable from another file". There are lots of answers. Have you tried searching for an answer to your question?

Comment: Check the answer on this post, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135131/php-getting-variable-from-another-php-file

Answer (score 2):

`include` and `require` are not functions, they are language constructs. Therefore they need to be used without brackets.

Either way, you missed quotes around `php-file_1.php`.

`include 'php-file_1.php';` should work fine.

Comment: You can use it with or without parentheses. It works the same.

Comment: Yes, but you shouldn't. "Because include is a special language construct, parentheses are not needed around its argument. " as per https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: it doesn't work. I included php-file_1.php in php-file_2.php and the variable isn't available in php-file_2.php. this isn't the way it should be.

Comment: should I open another question for the global variable question?

Comment: @BenjaminRöhling You missed quotes around your php file. Please have another look at my answer, because I tried your exact code and it works.

Comment: yeah! I missed them here but not in the source code. the problem was multi-problems. I'm not a novelist so I can't list them here. I'm taking a pbreak from programming.