# PHP How to use particular defines/includes from external source

Tags: php

I have developed a small PHP application that runs parallel and self-sufficient to a main application. This main application has a configuration file with defines (e.a. database connect configuration and so on...) that I need for my application. The problem is that this main application has defines and includes that are in conflict with my application.

The question is how can I use particular defines fom this configuration file, but not the defines and includes I don't want to?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP, getting variable from another php-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135131/php-getting-variable-from-another-php-file)

Comment: why dont you just not use the same nor for defines or  you can use boolean function_exists($function_name)  for function to check if they are defined already and use this for constant if(defined('FOO')) {
    // do something when it is defined
}
else {
    // do something else because it isn't
}

Comment: @Angelin Calu No, it doesn't. The configuration file contains a huge mix of existing includes and defines. Defines with the same name as in my configuration, but different values for e.a. path and so on.

Comment: @Hammad Ahmed khan configuration file has no functions. Only defines and includes. Defines I can overwrite, but not the includes or can I "block" includes?

Comment: With php file I can read the defines I need and get an array with all defines: https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.file.php