# how to write php base_url() in js file

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I want to send base_url from Controller Book to book.js

**This is my function in book.js**

```
function loadPage(page, pageElement) {

    // Create an image element
    var img = $('<img />');

    img.mousedown(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    img.load(function() {
        // Set the size
        $(this).css({width: '100%', height: '100%'});

        // Add the image to the page after loaded
        $(this).appendTo(pageElement);

        // Remove the loader indicator
        pageElement.find('.loader').remove();
    });

    // MY PROBLEM is here !!! Load the page
    // img.attr('src', '../../_library/book/samples/magazine/pages/' +  page + '.jpg');
    img.attr('src', '<?php echo base_url($source) ?>' +  page + '.jpg');

    loadRegions(page, pageElement);

}
```

Comment: This seems a little similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135131/php-getting-variable-from-another-php-file?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use php commands in js files. But instead you can define a variable between script tags in the php file. For example:

```
example.php

<script>
const EXAMPLE_VAR = '<?php echo base_url($source);?>'
</script>
```

And you can use it in js file like this:

```
img.attr('src', EXAMPLE_VAR +  page + '.jpg');
```

Comment: Thank's emrez. Your suggestion solve my problem.